# Applying Gravity : 2D arrays

Tags: java, reverse, multidimensional-array

My program consists of a grid composed by a 2D array.
The user input deletes certain elements of the grid, leaving blank spaces.
My issue is making the elements above the blank spaces drop down.

Originaly I had an array to check if a space is blank, and if is was blank, the element above would be deleted and recreated where there used to be a blank.

My problem is, the array I used to do this was Left->Right, Top->Down (i++, j++), this leaves me with the problem of having to repeat the whole code to get newly built blank spaces. (For example, if I delete something from the 3rd row, the 2nd row would be blank, but I'd have checked the 2nd row already.

Since it would be very uneffective (including overstack errors) I decided to do the reserve, bottom->top, right->left array (i--,j--), my issue with this is that I'm getting an array out of bounds error, even though I made sure its not possible for it to go out of bounds.

Here is the piece of code which is giving problems

```
public static void dropBall(){
 for (i =Settings.row-1;i>=0;i--){
  for (j =Settings.col-1;i>=0 ; j--){
   if (i <0||j<0)break;
   if (Settings.grid[i+1][j]==666){ 
    //checking if the space below has the 666 ID (666 ID equals to blank)                   
    Settings.grid[i+1][j]=Settings.grid[i][j]; //Deleting the current blank                 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Note:
`Settings.row and Settings.col` are similar to `something.lenght`, meaning they have the lenght of the grid, even though the grid starts at 0.

How can I avoid the outofBounds error in this situation?

Comment: _"Settings.row [...] are similar to something.lenght"_. So you're starting `i` at `length-1`, and you're doing `grid[i+1]`. So at the first iteration in your if statement, this is equivalent to `grid[length][j]`. That's why you get this exception.

Comment: True, I completly forgot that the bottom doesn't really have anything below itself, or at least nothing on the array being mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On line3:

  ```
              for (j =Settings.col-1;i>=0 ; j--){
  ```

change to:

```
                for (j =Settings.col-1;j>=0 ; j--){
```

- and you can remove the `if` line after.
- and start your `i` on `Settings.row-2` instead
- try this:

  ```
   public static void dropBall(){
      for (i =Settings.row-1;i>=0;i--){
         for (j =Settings.col-1;j>=0 ; j--){
             if (Settings.grid[i+1][j]==666){ 
                //checking if the space below has the 666 ID (666 ID equals to blank)                   
                 Settings.grid[i+1][j]=Settings.grid[i][j]; //Deleting the current blank                 
                 Settings.grid[i][j] = 666;
             }
         }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: That's true, As per the if-statement, I was somewhat desesperate so I made up limitations to prevent it, and the 3rd line `i>=0`, it was most likely due to switching from ++ to -- (for the 50th time), but honestly I didn't saw it.

As per starting `i` at `Settings.row-2` that is so obvious and simple that I feel dumb to forget to do that, and instead, trying to create 50 lines to prevent one error. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start from the second row at the bottom, and not from the first (since there is no row below it):

   ```
         for (i = Settings.row-2 ... // instead of row-1
   ```
2. Remove this line (it is redundant):

   ```
         if (i <0||j<0)break;
   ```